# How to create a simple but flexible Clean URL in .htaccess with Apache Mod_rewrite?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I have just started to be familiar with Apache Mod_rewrite and I have falied to achieve my goal.

I am building a website where I'd like to replace the ugly URLs with Clean, user firendly URLs. I have currently created some files already, but I'm not sure if I'll create clean urls, I'll be needing meny of these pages.

I'd have 2 questions, on how would professionals create this website, here we go:

### **1st question:**

I have the following file structure which you see below:

Main folder:

- index.php (Home Page)
- login.php (Login Page)
- register.php (Register Page)

  Under Main Folder I have: **Members** folder:

  - index.php (Dashboard Page)
  - stats.php (Statistics Page)

The first problem/question is the following:

I'm currently just using the simple **.php** pages to access it's content. Would it be better to use 1 index.php file and include the necessary files when someone enters the following for example: `/index.php?go=login` 
So would this be more professional than just providing the .php files and deliver their content when they're clicked?

### **2nd question:**

This question would be around the Clean URLs. I would like to achieve the following:

When someone visits: `http://www.example.com/index.php - it should redirects them to http://www.example.com/`

When someone visits: `http://www.example.com/login.php` - it should redirects them to `http://www.example.com/login/` - if someone types `http://www.example.com/login` that should also be processing `login.php`

As well as the other pages, like:

`http://www.example.com/register.php` <-> `http://www.example.com/register/` (the slash should be optional)
`http://www.example.com/members/dashboard.php` <-> `http://www.example.com/dashboard/` (the slash should be optional)

And so on...

I have already tried to create a rewrite condition, but it doesn't seems to work. Can anyone please update me on this?

What I've tried:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^login/?$ login.php [NC]
```

I really hope, that someone could help me to answer both of these questions. I have been searching for 2 days now, and I couldn't figure out what rewrite rule should I be using. Thank you really much!

EDIT:

Should I use a basic redirect and take care of the other codes using PHP? Please someone help me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This (untested) code should take `something.php` and redirect to `/something`.

Additionally, it should allow you to keep doing stuff like `/search?query=foo`, which will be the equivalent of `/search.php?query=foo`.

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^(test|login|whatever)/?$ $1.php/$2 [NC,L]
```

Comment: It actually gives me Internal error 500. I have wiped out (?.*) and it have worked, but it only works with /something, this doesn't work: /something/

Comment: Oh, you can jam in an extra `/?` between the two capturing groups. I know why it's 500ing, I'll just fix that up and amend.

Comment: Tested and amended. Should work completely fine now. Basically it's just taking any string and turning it into the PHP version. The query string is unmodified and works as normal.

Comment: Thank you it is working fine. However, how can I prevent users if they go to `test.php`? I want them to be redirected to `test/` if they go to `test.php`

Comment: You will get an infinite loop in this case.

Comment: @Radical_Activity this post might help you : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6342261/how-can-i-get-mod-rewrite-to-match-a-rule-just-once