# How to remove the .php and make it still work?

Tags: php, .htaccess

I want all of my files that end in .php, to work with out it.

So: site.com/me.php

Would look and work like: site.com/me

Is this possible, and if so, how?

Comment: You know, see your tags. So where is problem to find it on google?

Comment: I really don't know reason for upvoting this question. It's question by user who don't want to use google and this is not a specific problem which is not easy to find his solution but problem with adding 3 words into Google!

Comment: @user0000001, no, it should not be down-voted just because the user could have found his answer on Google.  After all, we want StackOverflow to be more reliable than Google.  However it _should_ be down-voted for the following:  _"Questions asking for code **must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results**. See also: [Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist)"_

Comment: I didn't write this question must be downvoted but I wrote this question has no reason for UPvote. It was upvoted when I wrote this comment above.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to change the PHP file extension using .htacess file on GoDaddy Linux Hosting?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7897353/how-to-change-the-php-file-extension-using-htacess-file-on-godaddy-linux-hostin)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

With google and some mod_rewrite, this should do the trick... But you need to add some lines so it doesn't always add it...

Answer (score 2):

Place this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

# externally redirects /dir/file.php to /dir/file
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/+(.+?)\.php[\s?] [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [R=301,L,NE]

# internally forwards /dir/file to /dir/file.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ /$1.php [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

I posted [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20424244/how-to-create-a-simple-but-flexible-clean-url-in-htaccess-with-apache-mod-rewri/20424383?noredirect=1#comment30507295_20424383) today. You need to add a .htaccess file to your document root and have mod_rewrite enabled on your Apache server.

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^(test|login|whatever)/?$ $1.php/$2 [NC,L]
```

Comment: Your code is not completed. It will work only for test/login/whatever pattern in URL.

Comment: I feel like specifying what pages to rewrite by going `(test|login|whatever)` completely defeats the purpose of regex.

Comment: It was a solution for someone else that can be appropriated.